# 301 redirect adds an extra word to the end of the target url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've tried a few work arounds but can't seem to find a solution that works. 
When I try to create a 301 redirect for a URL, the redirect seems to work, but appends a 'location' word to the end of the target URL, which is referenced in the URL that's being redirected. For example:

```
Redirect 301 /web-design/ecommerce/london/ https://www.orangegrovedesigns.co.uk/web-services/web-design/ecommerce-web-design/
```

Results in:

```
https://www.orangegrovedesigns.co.uk/web-services/web-design/ecommerce-web-design/london/
```

There are other redirects in the file but I've also tried deleting them all incase they were having an impact.

Full htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Redirect 301 /web-design/ecommerce/ https://www.orangegrovedesigns.co.uk/web-services/web-design/ecommerce-web-design/
Redirect 301 /web-design/ecommerce/reading/ https://www.orangegrovedesigns.co.uk/web-services/web-design/ecommerce-web-design/
Redirect 301 /web-design/ecommerce/marlow/ https://www.orangegrovedesigns.co.uk/web-services/web-design/ecommerce-web-design/
Redirect 301 /web-design/ecommerce/oxford/ https://www.orangegrovedesigns.co.uk/web-services/web-design/ecommerce-web-design/
Redirect 301 /web-design/ecommerce/newbury/ https://www.orangegrovedesigns.co.uk/web-services/web-design/ecommerce-web-design/
Redirect 301 /web-design/ecommerce/bracknell/ https://www.orangegrovedesigns.co.uk/web-services/web-design/ecommerce-web-design/
Redirect 301 /web-design/ecommerce/wokingham/ https://www.orangegrovedesigns.co.uk/web-services/web-design/ecommerce-web-design/
Redirect 301 /web-design/ecommerce/london/ https://www.orangegrovedesigns.co.uk/web-services/web-design/ecommerce-web-design/
```

Comment: Yep, first thing I did.

Comment: Sure. I've amended to include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have every rule using `mod_rewrite` like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^web-design/ecommerce/?$ https://www.orangegrovedesigns.co.uk/web-services/web-design/ecommerce-web-design/ [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^web-design/ecommerce/reading/?$ https://www.orangegrovedesigns.co.uk/web-services/web-design/ecommerce-web-design/ [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^web-design/ecommerce/marlow/?$ https://www.orangegrovedesigns.co.uk/web-services/web-design/ecommerce-web-design/ [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^web-design/ecommerce/oxford/?$ https://www.orangegrovedesigns.co.uk/web-services/web-design/ecommerce-web-design/ [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^web-design/ecommerce/newbury/?$ https://www.orangegrovedesigns.co.uk/web-services/web-design/ecommerce-web-design/ [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^web-design/ecommerce/bracknell/?$ https://www.orangegrovedesigns.co.uk/web-services/web-design/ecommerce-web-design/ [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^web-design/ecommerce/wokingham/?$ https://www.orangegrovedesigns.co.uk/web-services/web-design/ecommerce-web-design/ [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^web-design/ecommerce/london/?$ https://www.orangegrovedesigns.co.uk/web-services/web-design/ecommerce-web-design/ [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache completely before testing this change.